# WebPack - generated ouptut without webpackBootStrap

Tags: webpack

is there a way to direct the webpack to generate output without the boot strap code and generate something like:

```
webpackedmodules = [
   function(module, exports, __webpack_require__) {
      ...
   }, 
   function(module, exports, __webpack_require__) {
      ...
   }, 
]
```

or

```
return [
   function(module, exports, __webpack_require__) {
      ...
   }, 
   function(module, exports, __webpack_require__) {
      ...
   }, 
]
```

or with completely custom boostrap code.

I want to load this using XHR and have a custom "package resolver" which will later allow me to send specific modules to various web workers dynamically.